# Shell - negative file globbing

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

In Bash, to do a negative file globbing I have the following 2 choices. Is there a difference between them ? Both return the same result :

```
$ ls
f1.txt  f2.txt  f3.txt  f4.txt

$ ls f[!24]*
f1.txt  f3.txt

$ ls f[^24]*
f1.txt  f3.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[!...]` pattern matches a single character that is not part of the `...` set within the square brackets.  This is a filename globbing pattern used by POSIX shells.

The `[^...]` pattern works the same, but is a POSIX regular expression.  This pattern is not generally portable to other shells as a filename globbing pattern, but the `bash` shell recognizes it and treats it as identical to the `[!...]` pattern.

If you have a choice to choose between these two when writing a filename globbing pattern, you should most probably use the portable POSIX variant `[!...]`.

[The POSIX standard says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01) about the filename globbing pattern `[...]` in general:

> If an open bracket introduces a bracket expression as in XBD RE Bracket Expression, except that the `<exclamation-mark>` character (`!`) shall replace the `<circumflex>` character (`^`) in its role in a non-matching list in the regular expression notation, it shall introduce a pattern bracket expression. A bracket expression starting with an unquoted `<circumflex>` character produces unspecified results. Otherwise, `[` shall match the character itself.

The "XBD RE Bracket Expression" thing is [the specification for `[...]` in regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05).

The standard leaves the use of `[^...]` in a filename globbing pattern "unspecified" and the `bash` shell (and a few others) have chosen to implement this as identical to `[!...]`.

Comment: Note that the reason it's `[!x]` instead of `[^x]` is that `^` was a pipe operator in the Thompson/Bourne shell. It's `^` in regexps and about every other shell (except some direct Bourne descendants like ksh88). In csh, and interactive bash, zsh, `!` is a history expansion operator so `[^x]` is preferred there even though `[!x]` is supported in zsh/bash (though conflicts with history expansion). In rc / es, `^` is some form of concatenation operator,  it's `[~x]` there for negation. `fish` doesn't support bracket expressions.

Comment: (to clarify, `^` (which looked more like a ↑ at the time) was a pipe operator in the Thompson shell, but globbing was done with the `/etc/glob` helper (which gave their name to globs), and didn't support negation inside `[...]`. `[!...]` was likely introduced by the Bourne shell (which used `|` as pipe operator but kept `^` as well for backward compatibility).